# AWS Fargate docker compose instead of docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I am using Cloud Formation to deploy my image from ECR to Fargate. My image uses docker-compose but upon deploying Fargate is running docker run and am unable to find an option where I can instruct in my Cloud Formation stack to run the docker compose up command instead of docker run

My Cloud formation stack is:

```
{
        "Resources": {
            "VPCFARGATE": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
                "Properties": {
                    "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                    "InstanceTenancy": "default",
                    "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
                    "EnableDnsHostnames" : "true"
                }
            },
            "INTGATEWAY": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
            },
            "ATTACHIG": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
                "DependsOn": ["VPCFARGATE", "INTGATEWAY"],
                "Properties": {
                    "InternetGatewayId" : {"Ref": "INTGATEWAY"},
                    "VpcId" : {"Ref": "VPCFARGATE"}
                }
            },
            "ROUTETABLE": {
                "Type" : "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
                "DependsOn": ["VPCFARGATE"],
                "Properties" : {
                    "VpcId" : {"Ref": "VPCFARGATE"}
                }
            },
            "ROUTE": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
                "DependsOn": ["VPCFARGATE", "INTGATEWAY", "ROUTETABLE"],
                "Properties": {
                    "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "ROUTETABLE"},
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "GatewayId": {"Ref": "INTGATEWAY"}
                }
            },
            "SUBNETFARGATE": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
                "DependsOn": ["VPCFARGATE"],
                "Properties": {
                    "AvailabilityZone" : "ap-south-1a",
                    "CidrBlock" : "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "MapPublicIpOnLaunch" : "true",
                    "VpcId" : {"Ref": "VPCFARGATE"}
                }
            },
            "SUBNETROUTE": {
                "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
                "DependsOn": ["SUBNETFARGATE", "ROUTETABLE"],
                "Properties" : {
                    "RouteTableId" : {"Ref": "ROUTETABLE"},
                    "SubnetId" : {"Ref": "SUBNETFARGATE"}
                }
            },
            "SGFARGATE": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
                "DependsOn": ["VPCFARGATE"],
                "Properties": {
                    "GroupDescription" : "Fargate Security Group",
                    "GroupName" : "Fargate-SG",
                    "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
                        {
                            "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0",
                            "Description" : "Allow HTTP traffic on port 80",
                            "FromPort" : 80,
                            "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                            "ToPort" : 80
                        },{
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                            "Description": "Allow HTTPS traffic on port 443",
                            "FromPort": 443,
                            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                            "ToPort": 443
                        }
                    ],
                    "VpcId" : {"Ref": "VPCFARGATE"}
                }
            },
            "FARGATECLUSTER": {
                "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
                "Properties": {
                    "ClusterName": "Cluster-CF"
                }
            },
            "ECSTASK": {
                "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
                "Properties": {
                    "ContainerDefinitions": [
                        {
                            "Name": "johndoe",
                            "Image": "12345789.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/johndoe:latest",
                            "PortMappings": [
                                {"ContainerPort": 80, "HostPort": 80, "Protocol": "tcp"}
                            ],
                            "LogConfiguration": {
                                "LogDriver": "awslogs",
                                "Options": {
                                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/task-medium",
                                    "awslogs-region": "ap-south-1",
                                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Cpu": 512,
                    "Memory": 1024,
                    "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
                    "RequiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
                    "TaskRoleArn": "ecsTaskExecutionRole",
                    "ExecutionRoleArn": "ecsTaskExecutionRole",
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Key": "created_by",
                            "Value": "CloudFormation"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "SERVICE": {
                "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
                "DependsOn": ["ECSTASK", "FARGATECLUSTER", "SUBNETFARGATE", "SGFARGATE"],
                "Properties": {
                    "Cluster" : "Cluster-CF",
                    "DeploymentConfiguration" : {
                        "MaximumPercent": 200,
                        "MinimumHealthyPercent": 100
                    },
                    "DeploymentController" : {"Type": "ECS"},
                    "DesiredCount" : 1,
                    "LaunchType" : "FARGATE",
                    "NetworkConfiguration" : {
                        "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                            "AssignPublicIp" : "ENABLED",
                            "Subnets": [{"Ref": "SUBNETFARGATE"}],
                            "SecurityGroups": [{"Ref": "SGFARGATE"}]
                        }
                    },
                    "SchedulingStrategy" : "REPLICA",
                    "ServiceName" : "Service-CF",
                    "TaskDefinition" : {"Ref": "ECSTASK"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From what I can gather you cannot achieve this. Cloudformation allows you to create task definitions, which are the equavalent of a container configuration which can be run by Fargate. In the docker documentation (here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/) it mentions a docker compose command to create a CF templateout of a docker compose yaml. Maybe you can try that?

Comment: By the way; since I'm not sure myself I will keep an eye on this topic. Perhaps someone has a solution.

Comment: I realised the precise reason why I was doing docker-compose (multi container orchestration) is why people use Kubernetes and/or ECS

Comment: docker-compose is not supported directly by cfn. You have to translate it to task definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker compose up` instead of `docker-compose up` (without the hypen!)

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/

You will need to make sure you install the compose cli (https://github.com/docker/compose-cli)